# Batch Update: connection.commit() at the very end, with setAutoCommit(false), but data doesn't get rolled back

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, batch-updates, batch-insert

My Java JDBC call for a Batch-Update is structured as

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    //...
    ps.addBatch();
}

ps.executeBatch();

// Suppose an exception happens right before a Commit
if (someCondition)
   throw new Exception("test");

conn.commit(); // Commit at the very end
```

My understanding is, when that Exception happens, I never reached a `commit`. So my data shouldn't be persisted, right? As long as the `commit` is at the very end, and `setAutoCommit(false);` is specified, any exceptions don't require a rollback?

But I see that the data **does** get persisted. My question is why? And do I need a `connection.rollback();`? (This is with a Postgres DB)

Comment: An exception would only rollback the exception if Postgres was the cause of the exception. Anything you throw yourself won't affect the data in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the transaction isolation levels of PostgreSQL:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/transaction-iso.html

The [default is READ COMMITTED](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-set-transaction.html) which is good for you.

Reading back 'uncommited' changes depends on the JDBC connection you're using. Every connection will have a different 'view' on the data depending on the transaction isolation level.

Best practice when setting

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
```

is to have a commit at success and a rollback in a catch clause:

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
try {
  ...
  ps.executeBatch();
  conn.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
  conn.rollback();
}
```

Calling neither commit nor rollback will keep the connection open, putting load on the database for maintaining uncommitted changes. The JVM will then some time close the connection and the database will roll back all data.

JEE containers roll back transaction automatically when uncaught exceptions happen.

Comment: "JEE containers" may not be a well-understood term in 2020.  It might be prudent to clarify what that means these days.

Answer (score 2):

Every transaction needs to either commit or rollback to come to an end.  If you have auto-commit disabled and don't call `connection.commit()`, then it won't commit.

> any exceptions don't require a rollback
>
> So my data shouldn't be persisted, right?

The data is persisted in a way, yes.  Active transactions keep their data isolated, so statements which run on that same connection will see the changes, but other connections will not see the changes until commit is called.

Postgres uses multi-version concurrency control, which means that inserts, updates, and deletes essentially create "versions" of rows and Postgres keeps track in memory of which transactions can see which versions of which rows.

So what happens if your transaction neither commits nor rolls back?

Until the transaction commits or rolls back, locks will be held on the rows which changed in the transaction, which will block future changes to that same data.  This can easily lead to outages.

**Always commit or rollback your transactions.  Never leave them dangling.**

What happens if you *never* commit or rollback a transaction?

I'm not exactly sure what happens in Postgres or in your application.  Many networks have idle socket time outs, so eventually your connection will get terminated and that will trigger a rollback.  Postgres could also have its own idle transaction timeout (not sure - educated guess).  But never rely on these things.  You don't control the damage.

**Always commit or rollback your transactions.  Never leave them dangling.**

What does this mean in terms of your code?

When your exception is thrown, the call stack will unwind, jumping over the commit.  So your transaction will not commit.  Depending on where you catch the exception, the `conn` object may or may not be in scope.  Catch it in scope so you can rollback.  Why?  Because you should:

**Always commit or rollback your transactions.  Never leave them dangling.**